# How to filter laravel collection from given data

Tags: laravel, collections

i have a collection data

{
    "success": true,
    "doctor": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Dr. Mayank",
            "dob": "1975-01-01",
            "about": "This is description",
            "status": 1,
            "rating": 2,
            "rating_given_by": 1,
            "alternative_number": "7686876876",
            "profile_photo": [],
            "speciality": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Acupuncture",
                    "image": null,
                    "dashboard_flag": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "Acupuncturist",
                    "image": null,
                    "dashboard_flag": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Accident and emergency medicine",
                    "image": "http://192.168.16.21/remidify/media/174/detail.png",
                    "dashboard_flag": 1
                }
            ],
            "service": [
                {
                    "id": 78,
                    "name": "Correction of gummy smile",
                    "cost": "12.00"
                },
                {
                    "id": 77,
                    "name": "Dental aesthetics",
                    "cost": "43.00"
                }
            ],
            "clinics": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "akram",
                    "entity_id": 1,
                    "entity_type": "App\Doctor",
                    "contact_number": "2132132132132",
                    "status": 0,
                    "consultancy_fee": "12.00",
                    "available_today": "No",
                    "owner_name": "Dr. Mayank",
                    "pivot": {
                        "doctor_id": 1,
                        "clinic_id": 1
                    },
                    "address": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "address_1": "asdasdasdsa",
                        "address_2": "",
                        "locality": "downtown",
                        "city": "noida",
                        "state": "up",
                        "postal_code": "41561566"
                    },
                    "speciality": [],
                    "service": [
                        {
                            "id": 11,
                            "name": "Laminates",
                            "cost": "20.00"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 12,
                            "name": "Dental surgery",
                            "cost": "300.00"
                        }
                    ],
                    "clinic_image": [
                        {
                            "id": 7,
                            "model_id": 1,
                            "model_type": "App\Clinic",
                            "collection_name": "clinic_image",
                            "file_name": "1494863957588.566162.jpg",
                            "disk": "media",
                            "url": "http://192.168.16.21/remidify/media/7/1494863957588.566162.jpg"
                        }
                    ],
                    "id_image": [
                        {
                            "id": 8,
                            "model_id": 1,
                            "model_type": "App\Clinic",
                            "collection_name": "id_image",
                            "file_name": "1494863966218.348877.jpg",
                            "disk": "media",
                            "url": "http://192.168.16.21/remidify/media/8/1494863966218.348877.jpg"
                        }
                    ],
                    "location": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "latitude": 0,
                        "longitude": 0,
                        "entity_id": 1,
                        "entity_type": "App\Clinic",
                        "created_at": "2017-05-16 03:00:10",
                        "updated_at": "2017-05-16 03:00:10"
                    },
                    "clinic_timings": [
                        {
                            "day": "sun",
                            "opens_at": "09:28:00",
                            "closes_at": "21:28:00"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "education": [
                {
                    "id": 19,
                    "degree": "MBBS",
                    "university": "Univercity",
                    "year": "2017",
                    "entity_id": 1,
                    "entity_type": "App\Doctor",
                    "created_at": "2017-05-16 05:44:11",
                    "updated_at": "2017-05-16 05:44:11",
                    "location": "Delhi"
                }
            ],
            "experience": [
                {
                    "id": 19,
                    "hospital": "Hospital name",
                    "post": "pta ni hai",
                    "from": "1970-01-01",
                    "to": "0000-00-00",
                    "entity_id": 1,
                    "entity_type": "App\Doctor",
                    "created_at": "2017-05-16 05:44:12",
                    "updated_at": "2017-05-16 05:44:12",
                    "location": "Locations12",
                    "is_currently_working": 1
                }
            ],
            "registration": {
                "id": 1,
                "registration_number": "Reg # 2324324",
                "registration_year": 1975,
                "registration_council": "Council",
                "experience": null,
                "doctor_id": 1,
                "created_at": "2017-05-16 02:56:37",
                "updated_at": "2017-05-16 02:56:37",
                "adhaar_number": "232131231232",
                "id_proof": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "model_id": 1,
                        "model_type": "App\DoctorRegistration",
                        "collection_name": "id_proof",
                        "file_name": "1494863680447.329102.jpg",
                        "disk": "media",
                        "url": "http://192.168.16.21/remidify/media/2/1494863680447.329102.jpg"
                    }
                ],
                "registration_proof": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "model_id": 1,
                        "model_type": "App\DoctorRegistration",
                        "collection_name": "registration_proof",
                        "file_name": "1494863687436.266846.jpg",
                        "disk": "media",
                        "url": "http://192.168.16.21/remidify/media/3/1494863687436.266846.jpg"
                    }
                ],
                "qualification_proof": [
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "model_id": 1,
                        "model_type": "App\DoctorRegistration",
                        "collection_name": "qualification_proof",
                        "file_name": "1494863695576.803955.jpg",
                        "disk": "media",
                        "url": "http://192.168.16.21/remidify/media/4/1494863695576.803955.jpg"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "preference": {
                "availability": 1,
                "appointment_confirmation_method": "manual",
                "average_time": 7,
                "holiday_from": null,
                "holiday_till": null,
                "patients_per_hour": null,
                "preferred_appointment_type": "timeslot",
                "appointment_frequency": null,
                "preferred_payment_method": [
                    {
                        "payment_method": "cash"
                    },
                    {
                        "payment_method": "online"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "user": null,
            "doctor_clinic": [
                {
                    "doctor_id": 1,
                    "clinic_id": 1,
                    "consultancy_fee": "12.00",
                    "deleted_at": null,
                    "workdays": [
                        {
                            "day": "sun",
                            "available": 1,
                            "workhours": [
                                {
                                    "from": "09:28:00",
                                    "to": "21:28:00"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "service": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Now how can i find the doctors whose "about or specialty name" matches with some given search string.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should format this data if you really want someone to look at it, also paste the code responsible for this data output.

Comment: Its not letting us to edit because your post is mainly code, so provide more details and format the code. press ctrl+k to form code-block and inside it paste your collection data.

Answer (score 0):

Try using dd() helper and use like this below

```
$youcollectionvariables = { "success": true, "doctor": [ { "id": 1, "name": "Dr. Mayank", "dob": "1975-01-01"................. }

dd($youcollectionvariables)
```

you will see a formatted data and can find what you need clearly.

Hope that helps.